# recursive extract synonym for a new word from NLTK

Tags: python, module, nltk

Assuming I have two small dictionaries

posList=['interesting','novel','creative','state-of-the-art']

negList=['outdated','straightforward','trivial']

I have a new word, say "innovative", which is out of my knowledge and I am trying to figure out its sentiment via finding out its synonyms via NLTK function, if the synonyms fall out my small dictionaries, then I recursively call the NLTK function to find the synonyms of the synonyms from last time

The start input could be like this:

from nltk.corpus import wordnet
innovative = wordnet.synsets('innovative')

for synset in innovative:

```
print synset

print synset.lemmas
```

It produces the output like this

Synset('advanced.s.03')
[Lemma('advanced.s.03.advanced'), Lemma('advanced.s.03.forward-looking'), Lemma('advanced.s.03.innovative'), Lemma('advanced.s.03.modern')]
Synset('innovative.s.02')
[Lemma('innovative.s.02.innovative'), Lemma('innovative.s.02.innovational'), Lemma('innovative.s.02.groundbreaking')]

Clearly new words include 'advanced','forward-looking','modern','innovational','groundbreaking' are the new words and not in my dictionary, so now I should use these words as start to call synsets function again until no new lemma word appearing.
Anyone can give me a demo code how to extract these lemma words from Synset and keep them in a set strcutre?

It involves dealing with re module in Python I think but I am quite new to Python. Another point I need to address is that I need to get adjective only, so only 's' and 'a' symbol in the Lemma('advanced.s.03.modern'), not 'v' (verb) or 'n' (noun).

Later I would try to calculate the similarity score for a new word with any dictionary word, I need to define the measure. This problem is difficult since adj words are not arranged in hierarchy way and no available measure according to my knowledge. Anyone can advise?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the synonyms of the synonyms as follows. 
(Please note that the code uses the WordNet functions of the [NodeBox Linguistics](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Linguistics) library because it offers an easier access to WordNet).

```
def get_remote_synonyms(s, pos):

    if pos == 'a':
        syns = en.adjective.senses(s)
        if syns:
            allsyns = sum(syns, [])
            # if there are multiple senses, take only the most frequent two 
            if len(syns) >= 2:
                syns = syns[0] + syns[1]
            else:
                syns = syns[0]
        else:
            return [] 

        remote = []
        for syn in syns: 
            newsyns = en.adjective.senses(syn)
            remote.extend([r for r in newsyns[0] if r not in allsyns])

    return [unicode(i) for i in list(set(remote))]
```

As far as I know, all semantic measurement functions of the NLTK are based on the hypernym / hyponym hierarchy, so that they cannot be applied to adjectives. Besides, I found a lot of synonyms to be missing in WordNet if you compare its results with the results from a thesaurus like [thesaurus.com.](http://thesaurus.com/)